# resque redis socket timeout

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, redis, resque

I'm running resque on an EC2 cluster.  I have about 10 workers running on 2 large instances, and another large instance running redis itself, but every 3 minutes the resque workers get killed because the socket connection to redis times out.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve this issue? I am seeing the same issue. Any pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to set your `timeout=0` in your *redis.conf* so your servers will allow your clients to be idle indefinitely.  The default is 300 seconds (five minutes).

Another option would be to arrange to have your clients issue a Redis PING command every couple of minutes (the response should be the string "PONG").  I don't see any option for Resque to provide this sort of keep alive for you (though I do see references to a [keepalive patch for Resque](https://github.com/hone/resque/commits/keepalive).

(If I were implementing something like Resque I'd use any of BLPOP or BRPOP or [BRPOPLPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush) with a non-zero timeout option to support something akin to `select()` like polling.  Thus application wakes up every minute or so even if the queue(s) are idle to do some housekeeping (including running a "PING").